Can’t run Windows application
When I'm going to run the Windows application which I was running before without any problem, I get the following error:
002c:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00007FFFFE2FFEB0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation HEAP_INFORMATION_CLASS 1 not implemented!
0034:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00007FFFFE2FFEB0 0000000000000000): stub

It's emule if it's necessary to know. Besides I get the following dialog:

I'm not sure whether an update caused it, or if I did something which I shouldn't have done.

Not all programs work with Wine. Use a Windows VM/dual-boot instead

As I said, it was running some days ago on the same machine/os!

Make sure all necessary dependencies for Wine are installed. You can use tools like winetricks to install common dependencies.

How can I find what are the dependencies?!

@hamidi how is Wine installed on your system?  Did you update Wine recently?  Did the Windows program/software you use update recently?

@YukiEliot winetricks only does Windows dependencies within the Wine environment and prefix.  If OP doesn't know the dependencies needed for their software, but it was ALREADY working before an update, then it's less likely it's a winetricks problem and more likely some other Wine related change (potentially an update) that broke the application. Or, something changed in the software they run (maybe IT updated) and broke its compatibility with Wine.

@ThomasWard Yeah, I keep OS up-to-date and now I think I should not. Otherwise, I wouldn't lose its ability to run. Now I don't know what to do.

@hamidi If updates are your concern and Wine is what you're using to run your software you may want to consider having a Windows VM on your system with VirtualBox or such to run the Windows software.

sure, but running with wine gives a much better performance, because it runs natively. if i want to use vm it consumes much resource, at least more than running with wine.
